# My joomla website is showing Error displaying the error page

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

We are facing some issues in our website. I am attaching screenshot of the error. I need help, can anyone help me to overcome the issue. Only main domain pages is not showing all other installed sub domains are working correctly like 
bswa.org.pk/majestic 
bswa.org.pk/hrm

[image]

Comment: You don't appear to have attached the screenshot. Please ensure we can somehow see it

Answer (score 3):

Please check you have connected to correct Database of your site , Check below stuff in configuration.php file

```
public $host = 'localhost'; // Database host name
public $user = 'database_name'; //e.g root
public $password = 'database_password'; //e.g root
public $db = 'database_name';
public $dbprefix = 'db_prefix_of_ur_database_tables'; // e.g u5mip_
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by any number of reasons. You will need to set the error reporting to "maximum" in your configuration.php file (which is located at the same level of the index.php file, e.g. in the main folder of your Joomla site).

Typically, if a website fails all of a sudden without anyone doing anything on it, then it might be because it is hacked, or it might be something changed in the host environment.